# OpenLdap cannot use inetOrgPerson and residentialPerson together

Tags: ldap, schema, openldap

Is it possible to use inetOrgPerson and residentialPerson together?

I have the following entry to add to ldap

```
dn: mail=james@email.com,ou=development,dc=company,dc=com
objectclass: inetOrgPerson 
objectclass: residentialPerson
cn: James Lin
sn: Lin
l: the address
mail: james@email.com
```

in slapd.conf I have included the following schemas

```
include         /usr/local/etc/openldap/schema/core.schema
include         /usr/local/etc/openldap/schema/cosine.schema
include         /usr/local/etc/openldap/schema/inetorgperson.schema
```

when I try to add the entry via slapadd, I get the following error

```
additional info: invalid structural object class chain (residentialPerson/inetOrgPerson)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to have both classes because they are both STRUCTURAL and neither inherits from the other. This is akin to 'class' in Java where multiple inheritance is also disallowed. You could have them both if either or both were AUXILIARY, which is akin to a Java interface.

Answer (score -1):

Found this [FAQ](http://www.openldap.org/faq/data/cache/883.html) and it's not possible to have both classes because they are structurally different, so I have to choose one, which I think inetOrgPerson is a better option.

Comment: It is because they are both STRUCTURAL. You have misunderstood. See my answer.